# SQL: QUERY, IF Statement

Tags: sql, if-statement, lookup

I've got the following table with 3 columns

| date_actual | vehicle_ID | Parked |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-27 | 1234 | 0 |
| 2021-06-28 | 1234 | 0 |
| 2021-06-29 | 1234 | 0 |
| 2021-06-30 | 1234 | 1 |
| 2021-07-01 | 1234 | 1 |
| 2021-07-02 | 1234 | 1 |
| 2021-07-03 | 1234 | 1 |
| 2021-07-04 | 1234 | 1 |
| 2021-07-05 | 1234 | 0 |
| 2021-07-06 | 1234 | 0 |
| 2021-07-07 | 1234 | 0 |
| 2021-06-27 | 5555 | 0 |
| 2021-06-28 | 5555 | 1 |

Basically a table containing dates, vehicle_ID's and a third column that tells whether or not a car was in a compound (Parked). I need create a fourth column to this table called: Inflow. Inflow needs to give me the following output:

If a car is parked on date x, but was not parked on date x - 1, it should have inflow = 1
If the first date of a car that is available in the table already starts with a 1, inflow should be 0.

Hope you guys can help me out.

With kind regards,

Lazzanova

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. SO is not a code-writing portal, but intended to help you learn to advance as a developer.

Comment: Fair enough:

I tried using the lag function


```select t.*,
       (case when coalesce(lag(Parked) over (partition by vehicle_ID order by date_actual), parked) = parked - 1
             then 'true' else 'false'
        end) as inflow
from t;```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be describing:

```
select t.*,
       (case when Parked = 1 and
                  lag(Parked, 1, 0) over (partition by vehicle_ID order by date_actual) = 0
             then 'true' else 'false'
        end) as inflow
from t;
```